# Snap to top of window in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I make the window snap to the top of the page on an event in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest (edited based on @Aaron's comment):

```
$("html, body").scrollTop(0);
```

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for some browsers. If it doesn't, use `$("body")` (or scroll both just to be sure).

Answer (score 2):

This scrolls the window to the top of the page, if that's what you're after...

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```